# ES6 Exporting and Importing a Function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, script-tag, es6-modules

If I have an ES6 JS file (test.js) ...

```
export default function() {
  let foo = "test"
  return foo
}
```

With Babel, is it possible to transpile and call it in an index.html file

```
<script src="js/text-min.js"></script>
```

And start using the function without needing to import it into another js file? For Ex. the next script tag after would have the following code. This is in use with Webpack --

```
<script>
  var bar = new foo();
  console.log(bar);
</script>
```

Comment: Sure, use the options to expose the default as a variable of your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I solved this issue by providing an output var using Webpack.
Great article that speaks to this --
http://siawyoung.com/coding/javascript/exporting-es6-modules-as-single-scripts-with-webpack.html

Answer (score 0):

The transpiled version of the above code produces like this,

```
"use strict";

   Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
     value: true
   });

  exports.default = function () {
     var foo = "test";
     return foo;
  };
```

As you can see, it add a property to export object with the name __esModule . Nothing else. So you don't have a way to include this default function without using import or require.

Comment: if i want to make a one file transpiled plugin, in this case, there needs to be an import prior to the transpile? would the properties then be able to be accessed as a file?

Comment: if i leverage babel / webpack to bring down to one file, is it then possible to attach as script and access methods from the compressed file in another file?

Comment: @Yasir So you are using webpack? You should've stated that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually looking for is a global variable (which is probably not a great idea). For instance:

Module 1:

```
import {foo} from 'foo'; // still an ES6 module, just no export

// global variable 'bar'
window.bar = (...args) => foo(...args) + 6;
```

Then in Module 2:

```
bar(1, 3, 5);
```

Note that this defeats the entire point of using modules and should be used *very* sparingly.

Comment: this makes sense. the intended end use case is to treat es6 as es5 js that you add via script tag. the idea being you have the es6 way of doing it, exporting / importing, and a standard es5 way. intenedd to be a plugin.

Comment: it will be interesting to see how all of this interoperates once some browsers start shipping actual implementations.